# Filter coefficients with firpm

Tags: matlab, filtering

I am using the Matlab function here:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/firpm.html?searchHighlight=firpm

I have been told to use the following:

```
h = firpm(62, [0 0.09 0.19 1], [1 1 0 0], [1 300], {20});
```

The trouble I have is that the person who wrote that is no longer around and I am having problems to understand what "[1 300], {20}" means.  I think I don't need them but would like to understand them before I dismiss those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example at your link "FIR Bandpass Filter with Asymmetric Attenuation" seems good for explaining what the weights (`[1 300]` in your case) do.  If you care less about how well certain sections of your filter emulate the desired response, you can weight them lower.  In the example, they seem to care most about the upper stopband having lots of rejection so it's weighted highest.

`{20}` is the `lgrid` argument, which controls frequency density per the manual.